# Angular 6: subscribe does not exist on type void

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I want to display success messages to user after submitting a form.

form works perfectly when it come to submit the data but the flash message is not displayed and I get error: subscribe does not exist on type void

Here is what I have done ,

Html:

```
<form [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4">Comment author</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" formControlName="author" #author />
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['author'].invalid && (angForm.controls['author'].dirty || angForm.controls['author'].touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['author'].errors.required">
            Name is required.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4">comment description</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="description" #description/>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['description'].invalid && (angForm.controls['description'].dirty || angForm.controls['description'].touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['description'].errors.required">
            description is required.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button (click)="addReview(author.value, description.value)" [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MoviesService } from '../movies.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FlashMessagesModule, FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie',
  templateUrl: './movie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie.component.scss']
})
export class MovieComponent implements OnInit {
  angForm: FormGroup;
  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  constructor(
    private flashMessages: FlashMessagesService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private route: Router,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private activeRouter: ActivatedRoute,
    private moviesService: MoviesService) {
    this.createForm();
  }
  createForm() {
    this.angForm = this.fb.group({
      author: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  addReview(author, description) {
    this.moviesService.addReview(author, description).subscribe(data => {
      if (data.sucess) {
        this.flashMessages.show('You are data we succesfully submitted', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
        this.route.navigate(['/movie']);
      } else {
        this.flashMessages.show('Something went wrong', { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000 });
        this.route.navigate(['/movie']);
      }
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

and here service .ts
 a

```
addReview(author, description) {
    const uri = 'http://localhost:8000/movies/comments/';
    const obj = {
      author: author,
      description: description
    };
    this
      .http
      .post(uri, obj)
      .subscribe(res =>
          console.log('Done'));
  }
```

Here is app html component.

```
<div class="container">
  <flash-messages></flash-messages>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**Question**
what is wrong with my code? is this the right way to dispaly flash message? am stuck out here , any help will be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addReview()` method inside your service is not returning anything.  Instead of subscribing to the `post()` call inside your service, simply return the `post()` method.  This will make the method return an observable which you can subscribe to when you call it:

```
addReview(author, description) {
    const uri = 'http://localhost:8000/movies/comments/';
    const obj = {
        author: author,
        description: description
    };
    return this.http.post(uri, obj);
}
```

NOTE: You need to change the way you handle the subscribe to the service call.  You can read more about how that works in [the angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling).  Your service call should change to:

```
this.moviesService.addReview(author, description).subscribe(success => {
    this.flashMessages.show('You are data we succesfully submitted', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
    this.route.navigate(['/movie']);
}, error => {
    this.flashMessages.show('Something went wrong', { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000 });
    this.route.navigate(['/movie']);
});
```

Comment: After changing to that I get this error : `property 'success' does not exist on type 'response '`?

Comment: @Kaczkapojebana, I added a snippet of code to show how to properly subscribe to the service call

Comment: after also changing it return this error : can not find name author or description , i tried evene to declare them as public etc but still the same , what am I missing here?